# UIPickerView : Toolbar is not visible on UIPickerView

Tags: swift, swift3

function `pickerView()` Code called on ViewLoad

```
private func createPickerView(){

    picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width,height: 300))
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self

    let toolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height -
        picker.frame.size.height-50, width: view.frame.width,height: 50))
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:14.0/255, green:122.0/255, blue:254.0/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    // TODO need to update actions for all buttons

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.pickerDoneAction))

    toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    senderIdLabel.inputView = picker
    senderIdLabel.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

[image]

Comment: what is senderIdLabel?

Comment: senderIdLabel should be textfield

Comment: inputAccessoryView is there, but not showing. just reduce the height of PickerView. Set 180(for testing)

Comment: @JD.  senderIDLabel is UITextFiled ?? sorry for wrong label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pickerView height is the prob and no need to set from for Toolbar.Try like this it is working

```
let picker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width,height: 215))
          picker.showsSelectionIndicator = true
          picker.delegate = self
          picker.dataSource = self

          let toolBar = UIToolbar()
          toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
          toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:14.0/255, green:122.0/255, blue:254.0/255, alpha: 1)
          toolBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: Thanks alot ... it worked  issue was with height of picker view